# Sequelize creating SQL for DATE type

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I`m using sequelize with mysql and I want to know if there is a way to use sequelize to create SQLs like these:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DAY(dateAttribute) = 'chosen_day'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(dateAttribute) = 'chosen_month'
```

I`ve tried to do something like this:

```
this.test= function () {
    let searchingDate = "2017-05%";
    return model.table.findAll({
        where: {
            dateAttribute: searchingDate 
        }
    })
}
```

This works but it gives a deprecation warning saying that it will be remove in future versions.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So after a lot o research and reading sequelize documentation, I found the sequelize.fn. I didn't undertand everithing but it worked to solve the problem. 

here is the example:

    this.test = function () {
        return model.tableName.findAll({
            where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('MONTH', sequelize.col('dataAttribut')), 5)
        })
    }

But now I want to select register with MONTH AND DAY = 5.  In this code I got just register with MONTH = 5. I'm still tring to find a solution, if I got one i will put here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

So I used the sequelize.fn() with the Op.and function from sequelize. So the solution was:

```
this.test = function () {
    return model.tableName.findAll({
        attributes: ['myAttribute'],
        where: {
            dateAttribute: {
                [sequelize.Op.and]: [
                    sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('MONTH', sequelize.col('dateAttribute')), 5),
                    sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('DAY', sequelize.col('dateAttribute')), 5),
                ]
            },
            otherAttribute: 'someValue'
        }
    })
}
```

This code generated this SQL query:

```
SELECT myAttribute FROM tableName WHERE (MONTH('dateAttribute') = 5 AND DAY('dateAttribute') = 5) AND otherAttribute = 'someValue'
```

I hope to save you guys from doing this long researching that I made! 
Remember be HAPPY!